# "Layers were not correctly generated" error when polygonizing raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, image, polygonize

I have the raster of a river product of an image classification with the SCP Plugin, and i need to divide the land and the water that resulted of said classification, so i am attempting to polygonize the raster into a vector but i get the next message everytime i try to use the "Polygonize (raster to vector)" tool.

> The following layers were not correctly
> generated.
>
> - C:/Users/Hp/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_cb1e3046147541c89d55b1e9d1d5a866/processing_58f04a4d1739482fb515e029409908bc/ab79e4bee77147eab60fdcba4832ef51/OUTPUT.gpkg
>
> You
> can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more
> information about the execution of the algorithm.

Here is the [file that I am working with](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsiIvyBaodymgZxoHIZMLPkqdc88lg?e=6RkYTW)

[image]

Comment: The error is actually in the line "No module named gdal_polygonise".  I know the error window doesnt isnt too helpful. Did you try reinstalling QGIS? Alternatively, did you try running the tool on command line? You can check if GDAL is enabled under Settings -> Options -> Processing -> Providers -> GDAL

Comment: Have you tried not using temp output?

Comment: I will try to reinstall QGIS and i will update you and run the command. I also checked if GDAL was enabled and it is.

Comment: I also tried to now use the temp output before and i got the same result, i added the file that i am working with if anyone wants to give it a try while i reinstall QGIS.

Comment: Ok, so i tried reinstalling QGIS and it worked. I should have tried the oldest trick in the book. Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstlling QGIS solved the issue.